Azure B2C Verification Display Control UX014 Error
I am trying to set up the Verification control as per the example here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-control-verification which we are attempting to use as a "confirm another way" in our MFA flow, instead of using the authenticator app.
Unsure if I have it set up correctly but after the "SendCode" profile sends the code and returns successfully, I am faced with a "Bad Request" page, and the following information in the console:
code: UX014
diags: {"pageViewId":"6a176deb-72e6-4d71-bbc6-90490a6c1121","pageId":"SelfAsserted","trace":[],"truncated":true,"code":"UX014"}
p: B2C_1A_v1_sign_in_mfa
desc: Failed to send control action request

I have been unable to find any information on the code UX014 or the description "Failed to send control action request", I am wondering if anyone has seen this before and has any help?
Here is my current display control for the verification:
<DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControlMFA" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
  <DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <Actions>
    <Action Id="SendCode">
      <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MFAEmail-GenerateOtp" />
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="UserBackend-SendOtpEmail" />
      </ValidationClaimsExchange>
    </Action>
    <Action Id="VerifyCode">
      <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MFAEmail-VerifyOtp" />
      </ValidationClaimsExchange>
    </Action>
  </Actions>
</DisplayControl>

MFAEmail-GenerateOtp is copied from Microsoft:
<TechnicalProfile Id="MFAEmail-GenerateOtp">
  <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
    <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">600</Item>
    <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
    <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
    <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">5</Item>
    <Item Key="NumCodeGenerationAttempts">10</Item>
    <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otpEmail" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>

UserBackend-SendOtpEmail hits an endpoint, I am just returing an 200 OK status here.
**NOTE - ** I also removed this step and still got the same error, so it looks to be an issue getting/going to the next Action VerifyCode
MFAEmail-VerifyOtp is bolierplate code as well:
<TechnicalProfile Id="MFAEmail-VerifyOtp">
  <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
  </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>

Finally, my dispaly control is referenced in the following technical profile, which I believe is correct (should it be self-asserted?):
 <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailOTPVerification">
   <DisplayName>Email MFA Verification</DisplayName>
   <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
   <Metadata>
     <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.email.mfa.verification</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <CryptographicKeys>
     <Key Id="<key_id>" StorageReferenceId="<reference_id>" />
   </CryptographicKeys>
   <DisplayClaims>
     <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControlMFA" />
   </DisplayClaims>
   <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="MFA-TOTP-SessionManager" />
 </TechnicalProfile>

Trying to do a simple email verification and expected it to go to the Verify screen/action but it causes an issue at some point in the SendCode Actions or when it tries to start the VerifyCode Action.

This error can occur when there is an issue with the technical profiles that are used to generate and verify the one-time password (OTP) code. Based on the provided information, it seems that the issue is happening when the VerifyCode action is being executed.

check that the DisplayControl is correctly configured and referenced in the TechnicalProfile that is being used for the email verification.
